# How to fix errno 5 input / output in Odoo using aeroo report

Tags: debian, odoo, odoo-9, aeroolib

I've a server with odoo running, all was working ok but some days back aeroo reports stop working, odoo make the pdf file, but corrupt.

When I go to the config and try to connect to aerro report it says

```
Failure! Connection to DOCS service was not established or convertion to PDF unsuccessful!
[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

But docs is running ok. If I stop odoo, and restart it without rebooting the server, go to Aerooreport config and configure again it connect it ok. Never need to restart docs or aeroolib nothing, only odoo server.

using Odoo 9 on debian 8.1

In the logs:

```
2018-04-13 10:18:14,638 6411 DEBUG elfaro PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM IHDR 16 13
2018-04-13 10:18:14,639 6411 DEBUG elfaro PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM tEXt 41 25
2018-04-13 10:18:14,639 6411 DEBUG elfaro PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM IDAT 78 3699
2018-04-13 10:18:15,293 6411 INFO elfaro requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2018-04-13 10:18:15,327 6411 ERROR elfaro report_aeroo: Aeroo DOCS related error!
[Errno 5] Input/output error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 597, in create_aeroo_report
        data = self._generate_doc(docs_client, data, report_xml, print_id, deferred)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 434, in _generate_doc
        token = docs.upload(data)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/docs_client_lib.py", line 101, in upload
  self.url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers=HEADERS).json()
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen

   body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1039, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 879, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 846, in send
    print "send:", repr(data)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
2018-04-13 10:18:15,332 6411 INFO elfaro report_aeroo: End process report.aeroo_report_ar_sale_order (sale.order), elapsed time: 1.26793503761
```

could debug the moment when the report fails

```
2018-04-14 13:07:47,764 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM IHDR 16 13
2018-04-14 13:07:47,764 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM tEXt 41 25
2018-04-14 13:07:47,764 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM IDAT 78 3699
2018-04-14 13:07:47,772 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM IHDR 16 13
2018-04-14 13:07:47,772 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM pHYs 41 9
2018-04-14 13:07:47,772 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM iTXt 62 14830
2018-04-14 13:07:47,773 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM cHRM 14904 32
2018-04-14 13:07:47,773 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: cHRM 14904 32 (unknown)
2018-04-14 13:07:47,773 6570 DEBUG plastimac PIL.PngImagePlugin: STREAM IDAT 14948 31328
2018-04-14 13:07:47,883 6570 INFO plastimac requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2018-04-14 13:07:47,885 6570 ERROR plastimac report_aeroo: Aeroo DOCS related error!
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 597, in create_aeroo_report
    data = self._generate_doc(docs_client, data, report_xml, print_id, deferred)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 434, in _generate_doc
    token = docs.upload(data)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/docs_client_lib.py", line 101, in upload
    self.url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers=HEADERS).json()
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1039, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 879, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 846, in send
    print "send:", repr(data)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
2018-04-14 13:07:47,887 6570 INFO plastimac report_aeroo: End process report.aeroo_report_ar_sale_order (sale.order), elapsed time: 0.762506008148
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 597, in create_aeroo_report
    data = self._generate_doc(docs_client, data, report_xml, print_id, deferred)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 434, in _generate_doc
    token = docs.upload(data)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo9/OCA/aeroo_reports/report_aeroo/docs_client_lib.py", line 101, in upload
    self.url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers=HEADERS).json()
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/venv/odoo9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1039, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 879, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 846, in send
    print "send:", repr(data)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
2018-04-14 13:07:47,888 6570 INFO plastimac report_aeroo: End total process report.aeroo_report_ar_sale_order (sale.order), total elapsed time: 0.774438142776
None
```

after the broken pipe error, it stay down until I restart odoo and configure again aeroo report from config menu. If I try yo re-config odoo without restart i get the i/o error

Comment: Try to restart your postgres service.

Comment: need to restart Odoo service,and then reconfigure aeroo reports from config menu, it keep printing report for 3 or 4 hrs and again goes down